# Why var_dump for $this->data['foo'] is not working and for $data['foo'] is?

Tags: php, arrays, controller

In my controller I have this:

```
$this->data['post'] = $this->mdl_posts->get_post_by_slug($slug);
var_dump($this->data['post']);
die();
```

The output is *null*

However, when I change it to:

```
$data['post'] = $this->mdl_posts->get_post_by_slug($slug);
var_dump($data['post']);
die();
```

I get the nice var_dump of the whole array as I wanted.

My question is why the var_dump or print_r is not working with `$this->data['post']` and only with `$data['post']` .

I am using $this->data instead of $data because I am sending some variables from constructor to the methods etc. so I need to use it like $this->data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->data` would mean that `data` is a member of the class you are operating within.  `data` must be a variable local to the method you are operating in, but not a member of your class.

```
class MyClass {

    private $member = "123";

    public function __construct() {
        $this->methodCall("abc");
    }

    public function methodCall($nonMember) {
        echo $nonMember;       // valid
        echo $this->member;    // valid
        echo $this->nonMember; // not valid
    }

}
```